# не могу получить доступ с локальной сети к некоторым сайтам зоны ru

Tags: ssl, https, dns, сертификат

Имеется Fedora 39, к ней подсоединен роутер через вторую карту, и внутри крутятся на qemu виртуальные машины. На самом сервере доступ нормальный к ok.ru, vk.ru и avito.ru. А вот у виртуалок и в локальной сети нет доступа. Та же песня если пытаюсь зайти с телефона по WiFi, через роутер. Началось это недавно, когда были проблемы с DNS в зоне ru. Бораузеры, типа firefox говорят

> При соединении с ok.ru произошла ошибка. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR
> Код ошибки: PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

> Страница, которую вы пытаетесь просмотреть, не может быть отображена, так как достоверность полученных данных не может быть проверена.

> Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с владельцами веб-сайта и сообщите им об этой проблеме.

```
nslookup ok.ru
Server:     77.88.8.8
Address:    77.88.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ok.ru
Address: 217.20.155.13
Name:   ok.ru
Address: 5.61.23.11
Name:   ok.ru
Address: 217.20.147.1
```

curl выдает

```
сurl -v https://ok.ru
*   Trying 217.20.147.1:443...
* Connected to ok.ru (217.20.147.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Соединение разорвано другой стороной in connection to ok.ru:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной
```

При чем на ya.ru, и все в зоне com, не считая vk.com, доступ есть и он нормальный
Кто сталкивался? В какую сторону хотя бы смотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже у вас где-то блокируют доступ к `https://ok.ru`, как минимум по адресу 217.20.147.1 и порту  443.

Проверьте подключение по IP адресу:

```
openssl s_client -connect 5.61.23.11:443
```

Если пройдёт, то можно руками указать `curl` , на какой IP адрес отправляться:

```
curl --resolve ok.ru:443:5.61.23.11 https://ok.ru
```

Но я подозреваю, что те, кто блокируют `ok.ru`, заблокировали все адреса. Поэтому вам нужно выбраться за периметр - VPN вам в помощь.

Comment: мда, openssl виснет напрочь openssl CONNECTED(00000003) и все

Comment: но ведь с самого то сервера все идет, все хорошо. Не пойму

Comment: @maint На другие сайты по https доступ есть, или только с ok.ru проблемы?

Comment: vk.com, avito.ru, aliexpess.ru, sferum.ru - это то что только на вскидку, что не работает. Все из зоны ru, началось после свистопляски с DNS. На яндекс ходит, на всё вне России ходит спокойно

Comment: @maint сравните результаты tracepath с сервера и из виртуалок - пакеты ходят одинаковыми путями?

Comment: почти одинаково. Сейчас соображу как вставить вывод удобочитаемо. В виртуалках все кончается диагностикой Too many hops: pmtu 1492

Comment: перед этим идет куча no reply

Comment: # tracepath  ok.ru
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1492
 1:  _gateway                                             16.366ms 
 1:  _gateway                                              7.205ms 
 2:  xe-0-1-0.irkt-rgr5.sib.ip.rostelecom.ru               9.135ms 
 3:  185.140.148.155                                      82.269ms 
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply

Comment: @maint Странно это всё. За пределы локальной сети пакеты выходят. Но TLS содинение не устанавливается. У меня нет идей, сорри

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась назначением MTU на роутере для локальной сети и в настройках виртуальных машин